# Remove unknown special characters from file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I want to remove all the special characters except |, _, - and .s from a pipe separated file.

For example, my data file looks like..

```
ABCD|123|Name
EFGH|456|New-Name
IJKL|789|New_Name
MNOP|123|New*name
QRST|124|New/name
UVWX|353|Name_*%NAME
EFGH|456|New=Name
Eaba|456|New****Name
fdsf|456|New-----Name
iouk|456|New(#$%^)_Name
```

I have tried the below but couldn't achieve or I'm just half the way.

```
tr -cd '[:print:]' < temp.txt > newfile -- I still get all the special chars.
tr -cd '[:alnum:]' <temp.txt -- I get only aphanum chars but I want to have a few special chars.
cat temp.txt | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9|_-.]//g' | sed '/^$/d' -- I get all the special chars but repetition is there
```

The below gives me the output as

```
$ cat temp.txt | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9|_-.]//g' | sed '/^$/d' | tr -cd '[:print:]' | sort -u
""""){***+#=**~>>\+*****<(")
```

If I at least get all the unique special characters, I'll be able to put everything into a sed and replace with null.

My expected output is:

```
ABCD|123|Name
EFGH|456|New-Name
IJKL|789|New_Name
MNOP|123|New_name
QRST|124|New_name
UVWX|353|Name_NAME
EFGH|456|New_Name
Eaba|456|New_Name
fdsf|456|New_Name
iouk|456|New_Name
```

I need to be looking at specific column if that helps in reducing the code.  As said earlier, the code has to include |, _, - characters and remove everything else.
Let me know if you guys're looking for any more info.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I got your requirements right:

1. Replace groups of multiple `-` (e.g. `---`) with `_`.
   <sub>(If that's a typo in your example, simply remove the `sed` line in this answer.)</sub>
2. Replace all symbols other than letters, numbers, `|`, and `-` with `_`.
3. Squeeze repeated `-` and `_` (e.g. `---` → `-`).
4. Remove leading underscores in every `|`-separated field.

The following script implements these requirements in the same order (first line is for first requirement and so on). Note that `tr` is not line based and interprets newline characters like every other character, therefore we explicitly have to tell `tr` to keep the newline character `\n`. Also note that `-` has to be escaped in `tr`'s arguments.

```
f() {
     sed 's/---*/_/g' |
     tr -c  '[:alnum:]|\-\n' _ |
     tr -s  '\-_' |
     sed -E 's/(^|\|)_/\1/g'
}
```

Use this function like

```
f  <infile  >outfile
```

Comment: Thanks @Socowi.  This works almost fine.  I still get ---- which should be removed/replaced.

Comment: Also, I do not know what special characters I'll be getting.  So I would need to get the list and replace them accordingly.

Comment: Um, didn't you say to *keep* the `-` character? `----` is just 4 of them.

Comment: Yes.  I want to keep just 1 -.  but not ----. :)

Comment: Ah sorry. I should have paid more attention to your minimal example. Added a command to replace `----` with `-`. But what to you mean by `I do not know what special characters I'll be getting`? You only have to specify what you want to keep. All other characters are removed.

Comment: We're almost there.. Are we replacing those special characters with an _?

Comment: Aw man, today's not my day :(. Sorry for all the intermediate answers. This time I `diff`ed my script's output against your expected result and they are finally the same. However, you could have helped me (and others) quite a bit by clarifying your question. For instance, you wrote *»**remove** all the special characters«*  when you actually wanted to **replace** them with `_`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202190/discussion-between-santhosh-ram-and-socowi).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like by "special character" you mean non-alphanumeric. If so then just use the negation of the `[:alnum:]` character class to match those chars, e.g. with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and only changing column 3 since you said "I need to be looking at specific column":

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(/[^[:alnum:]-]+|--+/,"_",$3)} 1' file
ABCD|123|Name
EFGH|456|New-Name
IJKL|789|New_Name
MNOP|123|New_name
QRST|124|New_name
UVWX|353|Name_NAME
EFGH|456|New_Name
Eaba|456|New_Name
fdsf|456|New_Name
iouk|456|New_Name
```

If `[^[:alnum:]-]` is wrong then just use whatever character class you want and/or list the specific chars `[^*\/%-]`. Note that you don't need to handle `|` explicitly in the regexps since there can't be a `|` in a `|`-separated field.

Comment: I don't think I can use this sed as we don't know what special character we'll be getting. For instance, we've also got ¬ from nowhere.  Could you suggest any change to accommodate anything to _?

Comment: @Santosh the point of using the negated character class is you don't need to know what "special" characters you'll get since everything thats not alpha-numeric or `-` will be treated as "special". Why not try the script and see if it works or not rather than assuming it won't?

Comment: it did work.  thanks lot.. One thing I've noticed, a string quoted with double quotes been converted as `_string_` which's slightly making me worry.  Is there way to fix it?

Comment: Include that case in your sample input/output to show us how it should be handled but I suspect you just need to add `"` (and any other characters you don't consider "special" and so don't want converted to `_`s) to the bracket expression so `[^[:alnum:]-]` becomes `[^[:alnum:]-"]`.

Comment: Sorry, if my comment was misleading.. I want to convert the " to _ but i don't want to see a string like ```_string_``` with underscores.  So the _ before the _string_ should be removed.. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, please update the example in your question to include the cases you have in mind any any others not already included in your example and make sure to explain in your question how to recognize `"`s that should be converted to `_`s from `"`s that shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just some like this:

```
sed -E 's/[*/_%=#()^$]+|-+/_/g' file
ABCD|123|Name
EFGH|456|New_Name
IJKL|789|New_Name
MNOP|123|New_name
QRST|124|New_name
UVWX|353|Name_NAME
EFGH|456|New_Name
Eaba|456|New_Name
fdsf|456|New_Name
iouk|456|New_Name
```

Comment: The 2nd output line doesn't match the posted expected output.

Comment: @Jotne, I don't think I can use this sed as we don't know what special character we'll be getting.  For instance, we've also got ¬ from nowhere. :|

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/[^[:alnum:]|_.,*=/-]//g;s/[*=/]+/_/g;s/--+|__+/_/g' file
```

The first substitution removes any unwanted characters.

The second substitution replaces one more `*`,`=` or `/` with a single `_` throughout the file.

The third substitution replaces two or more `-` or `_` with a single `_` throughout the file.

N.B. The alternation metacharacter `|` and the substitution delimiter `/` can represent their real values inside a bracket expression so `sed -E 's/[/|]//g' file` will remove all occurrences of `/` and `|`. Also, the `-` within a bracket expression can represent a range, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` means any single alphanumeric character equivalent to`[[:alnum:]]`, but if it is placed just before the closing bracket, it represents its real value, so `sed 's/[a-]//g' file` will remove all occurrences of `a` and `-`.

The final substitution could be amended to `s/(-)-+|(_)_+/\1\2/g` which is equivalent to `s/--+/-/g;s/__+/_/g` if the user so wishes to shorten those extraneous characters.

Comment: I don't think I can use this sed as we don't know what special character we'll be getting. For instance, we've also got ¬ from nowhere.  Could you suggest any change to accommodate anything to _?

Comment: I would leave the -, |, _ and replace anything else with an _.

Comment: @SanthoshRam the first substitution removes all characters other than the ones you have selected i.e. `a` thru `z`, `A` thru `Z`, `0` thru `9`, `|`,`_`,`.`,`,`,`*`,`=`,`/` and `-` will remain, everything else will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -r -e 's#([^a-zA-Z0-9\|_])+#_#g' -e 's/_+/_/g'
```

However, you've got some inconsistencies between your expected output and the stated goals.

In particular, you state that you want to keep hyphens, but the you keep it on the EFGH line, but removed them from the fdsf line.

Answer (score -1):

```
  awk 'NR>2{sub(/New./,"New_")sub(/_..NAME/,"_NAME")sub(/_.*Name/,"_Name")}1' file
ABCD|123|Name
EFGH|456|New-Name
IJKL|789|New_Name
MNOP|123|New_name
QRST|124|New_name
UVWX|353|Name_NAME
EFGH|456|New_Name
Eaba|456|New_Name
fdsf|456|New_Name
iouk|456|New_Name
```

Comment: You don't REALLY think his data is always the words "new" and "name" repeated on every line do you?